# Is the linter giving a false positive regarding unique keys?

Tags: reactjs

```js
function renderRows(products) {
  return products.map(({ name, price, category, stocked }, index, currArr) =>
    // Is the category of the previous item in the array the same as the current item's category?
    currArr[index - 1]?.category === currArr[index].category ? (
      // If category is same, JUST render the product.
      <Row name={name} price={price} key={index} stocked={stocked} />
    ) : (
      // If it's a new category, render 2 rows...
      <>
        <Row category={category} key={"cat" + index} />
        <Row name={name} price={price} stocked={stocked} key={index} />
      </>
    )
  );
}
```

I have made a deliberate effort to separate out the `key` by throwing `"cat"` in front of one of the conditional renders.

[image: React Dev Tools shows unique s]

As we see React Dev Tools confirms that the s are unique.

[image: Console error regarding non-unique s]

Console shows this warning.

Now, if I do this without a conditional ternary render - no issues. Is there a better way to implement this? Is there something wrong with conditional render from inside `map`?

It shouldn't make difference, but here is the code for that `map`ped component, FYI.

```js
const Row = ({ category, name, price, stocked }) => (
  <tr>
    {category ? (
      <td className="font-bold">{category}</td>
    ) : (
      <>
        <td className={stocked ? "" : "text-red-500"}>{name}</td>
        <td>{price}</td>
      </>
    )}
  </tr>
);
```

To add more context, here is the data set:

```json
[
  {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$49.99", stocked: true, name: "Football"},
  {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$9.99", stocked: true, name: "Baseball"},
  {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$29.99", stocked: false, name: "Basketball"},
  {category: "Electronics", price: "$99.99", stocked: true, name: "iPod Touch"},
  {category: "Electronics", price: "$399.99", stocked: false, name: "iPhone 5"},
  {category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7"}
];
```

And trying to render as shown [in the docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment (`<>` short for `<React.Fragment>`) is missing the key, which is why the warning is displayed.

Try this:

```
function renderRows(products) {
  return products.map(({ name, price, category, stocked }, index, currArr) =>
    // Is the category of the previous item in the array the same as the current item's category?
    currArr[index - 1]?.category === currArr[index].category ? (
      // If category is same, JUST render the product.
      <Row name={name} price={price} key={index} stocked={stocked} />
    ) : (
      // If it's a new category, render 2 rows...
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        <Row category={category} />
        <Row name={name} price={price} stocked={stocked} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  );
}
```

In the code above, I've expanded the fragment to include the key and removed the keys from the children of the fragment (as they are not required for anything).

Comment:  I tried this. But I was trying to put using the 'empty tags' shortcut and that was a fail! So, I had right idea .

Comment: This is great. I did notice that in the React Dev Tools, now it shows some `Row`s without any . But, the warning is definitely gone. Strange that React wouldn't complain about the `Row`s with no s. ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is wierd React Dev Tools do not display the fragments correctly for the list (with the key). As long as all the direct children has a key, it is all good 